# Set search_path with H2 and Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, h2, liquibase

I have an issue with my project.

I'm using liquibase ( v4.8.0 ) and on the `changelog-master.xml` I include a SQL file taht contains that code :

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;
SET search_path TO public;
```

When I run my app with PostgreSQL it works fine, but when I run my tests that are using a H2 database ( h2 v2.1.210 ) it fails with that error :

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException:
> liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for
> change set
> db/schema.sql::raw::includeAll: Syntax
> error in SQL statement "SET [*]search_path TO public;"; expected "@,
> AUTOCOMMIT, EXCLUSIVE, IGNORECASE, PASSWORD, SALT, MODE, DATABASE,
> COLLATION, CLUSTER, DATABASE_EVENT_LISTENER, ALLOW_LITERALS,
> DEFAULT_TABLE_TYPE, SCHEMA, CATALOG, SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH,
> JAVA_OBJECT_SERIALIZER, IGNORE_CATALOGS, SESSION, TRANSACTION, TIME,
> NON_KEYWORDS, DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING, LOG"; SQL statement: SET
> search_path TO public; [42001-210] [Failed SQL: (42001) CREATE SCHEMA
> IF NOT EXISTS public;

I don't understand why it's failing and also I didn't find any help on the web.
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: Well, it fails, because H2 has no concept of a search path. You will need to mark your changeset so that it only runs for Postgres.

Comment: H2 has `SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH`: https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_schema_search_path

Comment: Thanks @EvgenijRyazanov for your answers, but, when I use an older version of liquibase ( v4.3.5 ) and h2 ( v1.4.200 ), it works. Do you have an explanation ?

Comment: `SEARCH_PATH` works only in PostgreSQL compatibility mode when you use modern versions of H2, I posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native syntax for H2 is [`SET SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH schemaName, …`](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_schema_search_path). This syntax is available unconditionally.

When PostgreSQL compatibility mode is enabled, H2 additionally provides `SET SEARCH_PATH` command with specialized implementation, it is different from `SET SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH`, because it adds `pg_catalog` first if it wasn't specified and it supports `$user`. To enable this compatibility mode you need to append `;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH` to JDBC connection URL. It is enough to add `;MODE=PostgreSQL` to make `SET SEARCH_PATH` available, but some other deviations between H2 and PostgreSQL need to be enabled separately, you may need them too. See documentation of compatibility modes for mode details:
https://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

This information is actual for the new versions of H2. Old unsupported versions have different options.